# Cannot start Pivotal-tc server in DEBUG mode

Tags: spring-tool-suite, debug-mode

I am using STS 3.6.4 Release.

I am able to run Pivotal-tc server in normal mode,
but it fails while running in debug mode.

It was working fine. I tried increasing server timeout to 480s, cleaning work directory etc, but it did not help.

Please anyone help me. Thanks in advance..

Comment: How does it fail, do you have an error message or any other additional information?

Comment: Error message is:Server Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1 was unable to start within 480 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.

Comment: How long does the server take to startup in non-debug mode? I would not expect it to be much slower when running in debug mode.

Comment: What are the tc server instance tomcat version, java version, profiles?

Comment: In non-debug  mode,it takes much less time.surely less than 45 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. Last time I worked with it, everything worked fine. In my case I saw that tc server tries to bind to random port ( like 50342 ). I have never changed my port configuration and it is still 8080/8443ssl/6969jmx. There are no any errors in the console. There are only logs from deployed application without any errors

```
tcp6       0      0 :::40950                :::*                    LISTEN      10772/java          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1637/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:6969          :::*                    LISTEN      10772/java
```

Port 8080/8443 are free of any other applications.

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

**Remove all breakpoints.**

From what you are saying - the server did not fail explictly, but it froze or was suspended from its execution. The suspending of the code execution could be caused by a breakpoint that was set by Eclipse or yourself. (I had a similar problem like this here: [tcserver is missing sunrsasign.jar in debug mode only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632644/tcserver-is-missing-sunrsasign-jar-in-debug-mode-only)).

What worked for me is the removal of all of the breakpoints.
You can also review logs of your Tomcat, so you can see if the server is progressing with startup.
If the server is running for a very long time - use [Debug View](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-debug_view.htm) to debug the particular piece of code on the server.

I had a similar issue when breakpoint was set incorrectly and suspended the server.

Good luck.